# Cakephp 3 elasticsearch issue

Tags: cakephp, elasticsearch, cakephp-3.0

I have installed elasticsearch on cakephp 3 As told here https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/elasticsearch.html. 
But I am getting an error

Error: Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) 
File /vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Exception/ResponseException.php 
Line: 34
Elasticsearch version -> 5.0 AND PHP version -> 5.6.30

Please help me if any one knows the solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no stable release yet that works with Elastica 5.x:

**https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search/issues/116**

The `1.0` branch is said to be somewhat 5.x compatible, so if you're up for an adventure, try using `cakephp/elastic-search:1.0.x-dev`.